# Why video calling not working with webrtc?

Tags: webrtc, pubnub, videochat

I am using the the pubnub [example](https://github.com/ajb413/pubnub-js-webrtc/tree/master/example), but when I am calling with laptop chrome browser to iphone safari browser it's not working.

When I try with Iphone safari browser to laptop Chrome browser then it's working fine.

Can anyone suggest me the solution for this issue?

Comment: Do you know if the issue is on the publish (send) side or on the subscribe (receive) side? Can you provide any logs/errors that you might be getting? Suggestions: Change the PubNub CDN lib to latest: `https://cdn.pubnub.com/sdk/javascript/pubnub.4.24.1.js`  Enable logging on the PubNub SDK to produce logs (console.log output): https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/pubnub-javascript-sdk-troubleshooting-guide

Comment: I wrote the OS example that you referenced, I can help. I tried the same set-up that you described, and the video call works for me. Do you see any errors in your web browser JavaScript console? Do you see any errors on the laptop side or on the iPhone side? You can check out the js console on the phone using a tool like jsconsole.com. Please let me know of any errors you see so I can assist further.